# Equivalent of MySQL's Compress function in Java

Tags: java, mysql, compression, base64, zlib

Want to compress text in mysql which uses by default zlib compression algorithm and then encode it to base64 string and then match those results in java so that in java i could decompress the text.Can anyone help me out with these any suggestions?

```
// Here is the sample java code:
String inputString ="have a good day"; 

   final Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");                          
            encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,   generateMySQLAESKey("default", "UTF-8"));     


            String encryptedText =new String(Hex.encodeHex(encryptCipher.doFinal(inputString.getBytes("UTF-8"))));

    Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
    deflater.setInput(encryptedText );
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new             ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);  
    deflater.finish();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (!deflater.finished()) {
        int count = deflater.deflate(buffer); // returns the generated
                                                // code... index
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    outputStream.close();
    byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();

    return Base64.encodeBase64String(output);


 //I want it to match mysql query like:

select TO_BASE64(COMPRESS(HEX(AES_ENCRYPT("have a good day",default))) from dual;
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Show us what you tried and what is not working

Comment: MySQL documentation. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_compress    http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_to-base64

Comment: I have already used mysql compress function

Comment: Can any one help on this please